# Extracting contents from factor or data frame

Tags: r, gsub

Here is an example of X - a factor (which is part of dataframe):

```
[1] "[[1]]"              "J48"                "------------------" ""                   "MSTV"              
 [6] "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                 
[11] "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "MSTV"               "|"                 
[16] "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                 
[21] "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                 
[26] "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                 
[31] "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  "|"                  ""                  
[36] "Number"             ""                   "Size"               ""                   "like"              
[41] ""                   "The"
```

I would like to extract the one word MSTV (which appears twice). I would like to ignore all other words and | signs. MSTV is accompanied with | symbols before and after its appearance. I tried to use the command:
gsub("[A-Z][1-9]:", "", X)
With no success. How can I extract the word MSTV (Which might appear anywhere in the middle between | symbols?

Comment: What is the `:` in your "command" supposed to stand for?

Comment: You could also do `ind <- grep('^[A-Za-z]+$', v1); v1[ind[grepl('[|]', v1[ind-1]) & grepl('[|]', v1[ind+1])]]
#[1] "MSTV"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("|","MSTV","|","s","",":")
str_extract(paste0(x, collapse=""), perl("(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)"))
#[1] "MSTV"
```

Comment: > str_extract(paste0(x, collapse=""), perl("(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)"))
Error: lazy-load database 'C:/Users/aw/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringr/R/stringr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: restarting interrupted promise evaluation 
2: internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: I got the following error:
> str_extract(paste0(x, collapse=""), perl("(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)"))
Error: lazy-load database 'C:/Users/aw/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringr/R/stringr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: restarting interrupted promise evaluation 
2: internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: I think you need `str_extract_all` here. Also no need in `perl` (update the package).

Comment: @Avi you need either reinstall the package or restart your R session. The problem is on your side.

Comment: Works good! Inspite of the following message (after installing perl package:
perl is deprecated. Please use regexp instead

Comment: yes, like I said, just do `str_extract(paste(x, collapse=""), "(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)")`

Comment: @akrun did you do copy and pasting without `>`? Which interpreter you're running since rstudio won't produce results like `#foo`

Comment: I just use `R console`